# paypal IPN successfully sent

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have set up a simple IPN using the code https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

However when I run the following

```
<?php
    include('ipnlistener.php');

    $listener = new IpnListener();
    $listener->use_sandbox = true;

    try {
        $verified = $listener->processIpn();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // fatal error trying to process IPN.
        exit(0);
    }

if ($verified) {

    if ($verified) {


     mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Verified IPN', $listener->getTextReport()); 
    }
    else {
    /*
    An Invalid IPN *may* be caused by a fraudulent transaction attempt. It's
    a good idea to have a developer or sys admin manually investigate any 
    invalid IPN.
    */
    mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
    }
}
?>
```

I am not getting any mail from my server saying it got the IPN from Paypal

Comment: Why do you have `if ($verified)` twice?  By the logic that you have in your code there, that inner `else` block would never happen, and hence you'd never get an email when an IPN couldn't be verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug in detail, one way is to write the log after each line into file and then check which step is causing the problem, also you can directly browse IPN URL and check if email for invalid IPN is wokring or not. There may be an issue with mail server configuration.

Comment: I have other mail scripts firing of ok, how can I do a log of what the server is receiving?

Comment: @RussellHarrower You will receive all the data through HTTP POST method, you can log POST array.